# How can I insert a new column after x on a table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `logo` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `information` TEXT NULL ,
  `announcement` TEXT NULL ,
  `role` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `yahoo` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `twitter` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `timelogin` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `UID_UNIQUE` (`UID` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `logo_UNIQUE` (`logo` ASC) , 
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

the problem is **that I want to add or insert a new row** like

```
`image_seal` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
```

***after logo***, can we do something like that in mysql ? append-thing?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: simply you need to change the table definition r8?

Comment: Btw, it's not a row which you insert, but a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN `image_seal` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER logo;

[Check here for Syntax of ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to add a new column to your table, not a row.
From the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/alter-table.html) it seems you can use the keyword `AFTER`.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN image_seal VARCHAR(255) AFTER logo;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: not fast enough :) At least you have the link for the MySQL reference

Comment: yup thanks mate, you save my time. i was googleing but i just cant find the right word "alter" for that. anyway thanks again. hope god repay you in someway :D

Comment: Thanks, great mind I don't know (speaks for myself of course ;) as this one was quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to administer your database? SQLBuddy, PHPmyAdmin and others can do this for you, without you needing to run queries.